# windows 2003 server folder redirect problem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, group-policy

i have installed windows 2003 server as a domain controller.

its working fine. i have also configured home directory for each user its also working fine.

in the group policy i have applied the folder redirection basic--> create folder in root path but its not working..?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787386%28WS.10%29.aspx).  It sounds like your group policy is not being deployed correctly.  Go through the following steps to figure out what exact problems you are having with group policy and report back here.

> To help determine what kind of Group Policy problems you have, do the following:
>
> 1. Generate a Group Policy Results report using GPMC.
> 2. Examine the results of the report to find the answers to three questions that are used in navigating the flowchart:
>
>    - Does Group Policy Results list the GPO as applied?
>    - Is the setting listed in Group Policy Results Report?
>    - Is the GPO listed in the Denied List?
> 3. Compare the results of the report to the flowchart in Figure 1.
> 4. Most of the results in the report map to core Group Policy problems in the flowchart. Investigate the core Group Policy problems first, even if the results of your report point to a specific CSE.
> 5. If the problem persists, assess whether a CSE is involved.
> 6. If you still haven't located the problem, you might need to look at log files to determine the cause.
> 7. If you experience a component failure, check the userenv log and see if the Local Security Authority has logged any events.